# jQuery Hide/Show if conditional statement

Tags: jquery, dom

I do this a lot:

```
var condition = true;
if (condition === true) {
    $('#condition_dependancy').show();
} else {
    $('#condition_dependancy').hide();
}
```

Can this be any cleaner syntactically? I could write my own:

```
$('#condition_dependancy').hidden(condition);
```

But i'm just wondering if there is anything built in.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

```
var condition = true;
$('#condition_dependancy').toggle(condition);
```

---

Side note: Don't use things like

```
if (condition === true)
```

unless there's a possibility that `condition` will have a different "truthy"* value and you only want the expression to be true if it's precisely `true` and not if it's just truthy. In general `== (boolean)` and (in JavaScript) `=== (boolean)` is just noise (although in JavaScript there are edge cases for using the `===` version).

Prefer:

```
if (condition)
```

and (for the `== false` / `=== false` case):

```
if (!condition)
```

---

* "truthy": In JavaScript, types can be coerced by expressions. Anywhere a boolean is expected, if you use something that isn't a boolean, it's coerced into being one. Things that coerce to `true` are called "truthy" values; things that coerce to `false` are called "falsey" values. The falsey values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course, `false`. Everything else is truthy.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea that toggle could accept this parameter. I included the '=== true' in my syntax to (poorly) express that this could be any expression being evaluated, not just a bool - silly really. But this is still a very good side note for anybody reading. (I'll accept this answer as soon as my 10 minute limit expires!)

Answer (score 8):

Using `toggle()`:

```
$('#condition_dependancy').toggle(condition);
```