# change shipment option based on email validation

Tags: jquery, html

I'm querying a database to check if an email exists / has already been used. if the email has been used I need to change a radio selector to another option

I have never used a toggle event based on a database query email validation so as of now I have the jquery setup returning alerts.

```
<!--/* shipment opt-in */-->
<div class="row--flex">
  <div class="form-group" data-sly-test="${!properties.defaultRefill}">
    <input type="radio" id="inServiceKit_shipmentOptInSupportingMaterials" name="shipmentOptIn" class="form-control" checked="checked" required>

    <label class="form_label" for="inServiceKit_shipmentOptInSupportingMaterials">
      Please send me the COPD In-Service Kit and additional Supporting materials
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" data-sly-test="${properties.defaultRefill}">
    <input type="radio" id="inServiceKit_shipmentOptInRefillOnly" name="shipmentOptIn" class="form-control" checked="checked" required>

    <label class="form_label" for="inServiceKit_shipmentOptInRefillOnly">
      Please send me the COPD In-Service Refill Kit
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/* end shipment opt-in */-->
```

```
$('#inServiceKit_email').on('change', function() {
  //ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url: 'endpoint',
    data: {
      'email': $('#inServiceKit_email').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == true) {
        alert('email is in database')
      } else {
        alert('email is valid')
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      //error
    }
  });
});
```

the form now shows the "please send me the COPD In Service Kit and additional Supporting materials" label, so if users email is in database I want that to change to the other label and radio check " Please send me the COPD In-Service Refill Kit"

Comment: You've posted some code and described a feature you'd like to add, however your code shows no attempts to implement the functionality you describe, nor have you really asked a question. It seems like a simple `.hide()` and `.show()` based on the condition. Please edit your question to ask something *specific*, and to include your attempt(s).

Comment: Additionally, if you're going to search for an answer to achieve this, note that the email validation, AJAX, etc, isn't really relevant. The question boils down to checking a radio button/toggling an element based on an `if` statement. There should be plenty of other questions to lead you towards that goal, ie: [How to check a radio button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery), [jQuery Hide/Show if conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541618/jquery-hide-show-if-conditional-statement), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments:

```
success: function(data) {
      if (data == true) {
        $("#inServiceKit_shipmentOptInSupportingMaterials").prop("checked", true);

        // This false may not be needed since they are in the same group
        $("inServiceKit_shipmentOptInRefillOnly").prop("checked", false);
      } else {
        $("inServiceKit_shipmentOptInRefillOnly").prop("checked", true);

        // This false may not be needed since they are in the same group
        $("#inServiceKit_shipmentOptInSupportingMaterials").prop("checked", true);
      }
    }
```

If the version of jQuery is less than 1.6 use:

```
success: function(data) {
      if (data == true) {
        $("#inServiceKit_shipmentOptInSupportingMaterials").attr('checked', 'checked');
      } else {
        $("inServiceKit_shipmentOptInRefillOnly").attr('checked', 'checked');
      }
    }
```

To check which radio button was selected, you can use:

```
$('input[name=shipmentOptIn]:checked').val()
```

While having the `required` in all inputs makes it clear and even encourage, if they have the same name, then you only need one of them to have the `required` keyword. Unless, they are generated dynamically.